# Regular Expression which allow space in between name only?

Tags: regex, zk

I am trying to write regular expression which work on these condition

1. Not Allow any space when nothing entered in textbox
2. Not allow space before and after the string.
3. Allow Space in between two keyword like `Ram Singh` should be valid
4. Only `Ram` Should be also valid

I am trying it in **ZK framework** and tried this code

but this is not allowing space in between two keywords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just use `^[a-zA-Z]+\s?[a-zA-Z]+$`.   [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/bC1zA1/2)

Comment: It would allow only RAM as well?

Comment: No. Please specify the exact input and output.

Comment: @anubhava - yes.. you are right. will change my answer.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
str.matches("|((\\w+ )*\\w+)?")
```

Comment: Sorry but i am trying it in web page not in java code

Comment: @askkuber Well, then take just the regex, and ignore the Java part.

Comment: Then you should not add the java tag to your question

Comment: @RohitJain ZK Framework work on Java and its ZK framework attribute